# Get records from one to many records from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Want to retrieve records from one to many relationships in a way that one record from main table and another one from many relationship table.

Exact issue:
Table 1 with 'user_devices' which is having ids of devices that user having with user_id mapping.

Now from Table 2, which is having many records that for users devices. Name is 'collection_datas'.

I want to have most recent record from collection_datas table which is having server_time as most recent and also want to map with main userdevice table.

so final records should have all records from user_devices table with 1 record associated from collection_datas table with that server_time

For more detailed info see table fields as below:

Table 1 'user_devices':
`id`
`user_id`
`device_id`

Table 2 'collection_datas'
`id`
`device_id`
`server_time`

The expected result should have records

server_time > Y-m-d H:i:s (ex: 2020-08-07 11:23:00)

How can I use MAX any suggestion?

```
Sample data of Table user_devices
id user_id device_id
1  170     1
2  170     2
3  170     3

Table 2 'collection_datas'
id device_id server_time
1  1         2020-08-07 11:23:00
2  1         2020-08-06 12:43:00
3  2         2020-08-07 12:32:00
4  2         2020-08-07 12:44:34
5  2         2020-08-07 13:43:32
6  3         2020-08-08 11:35:32
7  3         2020-08-08 12:35:32
```

above are sample data. I want to have records from table users_devices and 1 record from table 2 with the latest server time.

I think the above should be sufficient.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: i don't see any valid data sample

Comment: @scaisEdge, I have updated the question by providing sample data and after provided what needs to result please check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

the most recent data for each device  should be

```
select device_id, max(server_time)
from collection_datas
group by  device_id
```

and if you need the user id too

```
select c.device_id, max(c.server_time), u.user_id
from collection_datas c
INNER JOIN user_devices ON  u u.device_id = c.device_id
group by  device_id
```

Comment: SELECT c.device_id, MAX(c.server_time), u.user_id
FROM collection_datas c
INNER JOIN user_devices u ON u.device_id = c.device_id
GROUP BY device_id

This is not working giving error Error Code: 1055
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'u.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by